# Make cursor pointer in Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

We use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for our reports. On click of a chart, a new tab/window should open. I am able to achieve that by handling the click event in chart. But I am unable to make cursor as pointer.

Answer (score 14):

Yes,
this is possible. See [cursor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.cursor).
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-cursor-column/) (from that link).
Basically you set cursor option for the series:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        alert('You just clicked the graph');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want to make the whole chart clickable then you need to handle mouse hover/over. But then you may lose detail on where you are clicking (want to click series point but now you cant because you captured it on the "top" layer).

Comment: That seems like a strange place to set a point cursor to be pointer. Especially if only some of the points can be clicked.